# understanding how a view is set - android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am trying to understand the [android bootstrap](https://www.androidbootstrap.com) source code. So in some activity : I found something like

```
pager.setAdapter(new BootstrapPagerAdapter(getResources(), getSupportFragmentManager()));
indicator.setViewPager(pager);
pager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

where `pager` is referenced as `@InjectView(R.id.some_id) ViewPager pager;` and

```
public class BootstrapPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final Resources resources;
// ...
public BootstrapPagerAdapter(Resources resources, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.resources = resources;
}
//...
```

and some methods latter

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            NewsListFragment newsFragment = new NewsListFragment();
            newsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return newsFragment;
//...
```

In fact, I noticed that the `NewsListFragment` fragment is the one (the view of which is the first displayed) used at first when I launch the `ADB`, but I can't understand how this method `getItem` is called (the same way I don't understand where `setCurrentItem()` method is called). Could someone help ?